# picasa gdata python client API GooglePhotosException: 413, 'Request Entity Too Large'

Tags: python, gdata, picasa

I am using the picasa [gdata python client library](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/downloads/list) to upload photos and videos to picasa. The code works well for small photos and videos. But if the video is larger than 100 MB, I get the following error:

```
photo = gd_client.InsertPhotoSimple( album_url, title, title, file, content_type=mime)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdata/photos/service.py", line 470, in InsertPhotoSimple
content_type)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gdata/photos/service.py", line 428, in InsertPhoto
raise GooglePhotosException(e.args[0])
```

gdata.photos.service.GooglePhotosException: (413, 'Request Entity Too Large', 'Video file size exceeds 104857600')

Essentially server is rejecting the files larger than 100MB. However, [this documentation](https://support.google.com/picasa/answer/43879?hl=en) tells that file size limit is actually 1GB.

So, why am I getting this error? Anyone seen this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limitation set by the api, as per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#VideoLimitations), is 100MB. The limit you found is on their site, they have different rules for how *they* can access their service vs. how *other people* can access their service.